# Allow OP to override the result of suggested-edits review

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

### Background

Currently all suggested edits with code changes are rejected. Some people belive that a suggested edit that fixes the code should not be rejected, I don't see any other option because:

- If everybody would skip edits in code that he does not understand it would fill up the queue and waste the time of much more reviewers. For the same reasons we already reject minor edits.
- Reviewing other queues does NOT require special expertise to review. Why should suggested edits different?

### Suggestion

But there is a user that *should* have the nessecary expertise: the original poster (OP).
The OP has already a binding vote on suggested edits, but if the edit was rejected in the mean time, he has to edit the post itself, while the edit is still rejected.

So my suggestion is to let the OP override the suggested edit AFTER it was aproved/rejected if there were no other edits in the mean time*.

<sub>* How should a suggested edit be done if someone else edits the post after it was rejected?</sub>

Comment: *Reviewing other queues does NOT require special expertise to review*. Reviewing dupe votes can require specialist expertise to recognize if the other post is indeed a dupe.

Comment: Semantics: it's not really "override the review result", it's more like "insta-edit, using the rejected edit suggestion source". Overriding approved suggested edits is already possible by rolling back the edit.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'd like to see that such an "override" would grant/revoke the 2 rep bonus for the editor, that it shows up in the suggested edit as accepted/rejected. Basically: if the post has not been edited since the suggested edit was approved/rejected, allow the op to cast his binding vote.

Comment: I see your point, but personally think it's too complicated especially considering the rare cases where it's needed. Adding a button like "edit using this suggestion source" would be much more simple to implement, thus has better chances of getting done at some point.

Comment: I don't think that there are rare cases: If a user sees an error in some code, he could edit it, add a comment (good comments are good), reviewers reject it, OP approves.